# Is it possible to change the default axes in 2D?

Tags: 2d, axis

In 2D, the axes are set up so that X is horizontal, which is very intuitive, but for the vertical axis you have 'Z', which is counter-intuitive for someone working in 2D space. (As explained in the comments, when working in 3D the Z-axis is naturally up-down).

Is there a way to change the default so that Y represents the vertical axis?

[image: Default 2D axes]

Comment: Well, it is not counter-intuitive for Blender users, where Z is the up axis... like in 3DS Max for example. This comes from conventions of older architecture or CAD software, because you usually had a floor plan in a top-down view occupying the XY plane. Z was then the depth or up/down axis. I originally came from C4D where it is different than in Blender as well, but never felt the need to switch it. It might be important if you export for other software like Unity etc., but some exporters like the FBX exporter let you set the _Forward_ and _Up_ axes (and set them by default set to -Z and Y).

Comment: Ran out of space... concluding I wanted to say, as far as I know there is no way of changing the default orientation of Blender's coordinate system. There have already been questions in the past about it, but no answer on how you could do it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the explanation. Coming from a 2D perspective (pun intended) that is not immediately obvious.

Comment: I'm not quite sure though what you mean by generally saying "in 2D" though, Blender has different 2D views. _Front_ view with `Numpad 1` which you show in the question, _Right_ view (`Numpad 3`) with Y to the left/right, Z up/down and X in/out. Then there is _Top_ view (`Numpad 7`)  with X left/right, Y up/down and Z in/out. And furthermore the opposite  views by either pressing `Ctrl` before the numbers or simply pressing `Numpad 9` for the opposite of the current view. So, do you just want a different view or change the internal coordinate system of Blender (the latter is not possible)?

Comment: I think the reason that the 2D floor is in XY is because in Blender, your drawings are first-class 3D objects which have to play intelligibly with other 3D objects, made in other modes. What you lose in conventional familiarity, you gain in consistency (and power). It's more than arguable, though. IMO, better for Blender's precursors to have been created with the conventional World view aligned to conventional Camera view, Z depth, Y up.

Comment: A camera without rotation looks down, therefore the standard view is with Z depth. And the camera also sees Y up. It makes sense for the 2D view to use XY letters which are the first of the 3 coordinate letters.

Comment: Hello, @mydoghasworms .. I don't think you will get any  archival answers here that can add anything to the suggested duplicate.. which is why the commentary is expanding.. so I think it's fair to close this question as a duplicate. I'm afraid the short answer is "no, you can't", and hope the discussion here is some compensation. Unfortunately, SE sites are not discussion forums.